# apply webkit filter on a portion of a jpg image

Tags: html, css, webkit

Using this css

```
-webkit-filter: brightness(50%);
```

I apply brightness filter to an image, how could I apply this filter only to a rectangular portion of the image?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

That's impossible, you could add a clipped image with filter on top of it though. Not the most elegant solution, but it works:

HTML:

```
<div class="holder">
  <img src="http://placekitten.com/200" />
  <img src="http://placekitten.com/200" class="brighten" />
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.holder {
  position:relative
}
img.brighten {
  top:0;
  left:0;
  position:absolute;
  clip: rect(10px, 140px, 140px, 10px);
  -webkit-filter: brightness(50%);
}
```

The `clip` property limits it to the rectanglular portion..

Fiddle: 
http://jsfiddle.net/q3bmW/2/